# Laravel 5.5 Remove login from URL to open login page

Tags: php, laravel

My example url is http://project.net/admin/login

if i hit the above URL then it is working properly and redirects to login page, but i want to remove login from URL like this,

http://project.net/admin

then give a blank page.(here redirect to login page) so, i want same result from both url. how it is possible using laravel 5.5 OR any other way?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you actually want to redirect user to login when he hits /admin if not logged in?

Comment: i want to redirect login page if user not login

Comment: I solved a write htaccess rule in htaccess file like below:

_RedirectMatch "^/admin/?$" "http://project.net/admin/login"_

Thanks for your valuable help @everyone

Comment: Yes, but that way, you will always get redirected from /admin/ and /admin/ prefixed paths.

Comment: In my case, htaccess rule working proper and i got what i want. @niklaz

Comment: yes, but if you want to use /admin/ path, it will always redirect you to /admin/login page.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i do not want to admin path. Thanks @niklaz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176265/discussion-between-hitesh-makodiya-and-niklaz).

Answer (score 1):

If /admin route is already created, you can use

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate
```

Auth middleware

And add to this route

```
Route::get('admin', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

It will redirect user to login. 
You can also override this middleware with your own handle that will specify the login route.

Other way is to use `Auth` facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

//place this within method for admin route: 
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Auth** middleware

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
      Route::get('/', 'SigninController@view')->name('login');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
        *PUT YOUR ROUTES HERE*
});
```

Make sure you have added "use **Auth**" or it's facade on top of your Controller

You can know more about laravel middlewares [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware)

Answer (score 0):

define another route without /login and redirect it in login page using get or post whatever the method you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this on your route file

```
Route::get('/admin', 'admin@login');
```

Comment: He wants to redirect user to login page if not logged in and accesses admin route